how to split ID's into separate groups based on what they have
I have a work problem I've been looking at for a bit, I've created a very simple example, and this could be easy and I'm just overthinking it, or the complete opposite. I just need another pair of eyes or brain to help me out.
Here's a SQLFiddle - https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=b18e6800-424f-49b1-a324-df1c89fc482f
CREATE TABLE Party 
(
    Partyid varchar(10),
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    FruitCode Varchar(50),
    Description VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Party(PartyID, Name, FruitCode, Description) VALUES ('123','John', 'A', 'Apple');
INSERT INTO Party(PartyID, Name, FruitCode, Description) VALUES ('456','Jane', 'O', 'Orange');
INSERT INTO Party(PartyID, Name, FruitCode, Description) VALUES ('789', 'Jack', 'A', 'Apple');
INSERT INTO Party(PartyID, Name, FruitCode, Description) VALUES ('789', 'Jack', 'O', 'Orange');
INSERT INTO Party(PartyID, Name, FruitCode, Description) VALUES ('012', 'Jill', 'O', 'Apple');
INSERT INTO Party(PartyID, Name, FruitCode, Description) VALUES ('123', 'John', 'O', 'Orange');

SELECT * FROM Party

What I'm trying to achieve is to split each of these people into their own groups depending on which type of fruit they have. There's 3 possible groups, Apple, Orange, and both Apple and Orange.
John and Jack should belong to the group that have both fruits, while Jane and Jill belong to groups who possess Oranges and Apples respectively.
Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

What does the result look like?

SELECT
  PartyID,
  Name, 
  STRING_AGG(FruitCode,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FruitCode),
  STRING_AGG(Description,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FruitCode) 
FROM Party 
GROUP BY Name, PartyID;

output:



PartyID
Name






012
Jill
O
Orange


123
John
A,O
Apple,Orange


456
Jane
O
Orange


789
Jack
A,O
Apple,Orange



https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=7613a3b4-e8fa-4436-993b-ed87f0762ae4
STRING_AGG

Concatenates the values of string expressions and places separator values between them. The separator isn't added at the end of string.


@charlieface  thanks for the addition of WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FruitCode), which makes the answer better because the fruitCodes will be in the same order as the descriptions.

Conceptually, you just need to group by the concatenated value of all the fruit that each party has.
Unfortunately, this is not always as simple as using STRING_AGG() to make a CSV of the group codes because it's order of items is indeterminate in older compatibility levels of SQL Server and might produce the following output: SqlFiddle
SELECT PartyID, Name, STRING_AGG(FruitCode,',') as FruitCodes 
FROM Party
GROUP BY PartyID, Name




PartyId
Name
FruitCodes




012
Jill
O


123
John
O,A


456
Jane
O


789
Jack
A,O



Note that John and Jack are not in the same group, If that is a problem, then we need to fix the O,A and A,O to produce the same output.
In SQL Server 2017 the WITHIN GROUP order clause was added to STRING_AGG() but this is not fully supported by lower compatibility levels on all servers, if it is supported the simplest option just requires you to add the order clause:
SELECT PartyID, Name, STRING_AGG(FruitCode,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FruitCode ASC) as FruitCodes 
FROM Party
GROUP BY PartyID, Name




PartyId
Name
FruitCodes




012
Jill
O


123
John
A,O


456
Jane
O


789
Jack
A,O




Fundamentally in relational database schemas, Fruit in this case is a candidate for it's own table. When this is a table reference then we could add metadata to the table that can help us in situations like this.


For older compatibility levels...
We can however use FOR XML PATH('') in this case as it allows us to control the order of the records when the aggregation occurs: SqlFiddle FOR XML
SELECT [PartyID], [Name], [FruitCode], [Description], [FruitCodes].[Codes] as [GroupCode]    
FROM [Party] 
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT [FruitCode] + ','
        FROM [Party] AS [lookup] 
        WHERE [lookup].[PartyID] = [Party].[PartyID]
        ORDER BY [FruitCode] DESC
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) FruitCodes ([Codes]);




PartyID
Name
FruitCode
Description
GroupCode




123
John
A
Apple
O,A,


456
Jane
O
Orange
O,


789
Jack
A
Apple
O,A,


789
Jack
O
Orange
O,A,


012
Jill
O
Orange
O,


123
John
O
Orange
O,A,



Then you can use a GROUP BY over the top of this if you want.
The following shows the difference between String Agg and an ordered FOR XML:
SELECT [PartyID], [Name], [FruitCodes].[Codes] as [GroupCode], STRING_AGG([Description],', ') as Fruit  
FROM [Party] 
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT [FruitCode] + ','
        FROM [Party] AS [lookup] 
        WHERE [lookup].[PartyID] = [Party].[PartyID]
        ORDER BY [FruitCode] DESC
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) FruitCodes ([Codes])
GROUP BY [PartyID], [Name], [FruitCodes].[Codes];




PartyID
Name
GroupCode
Fruit




012
Jill
O,
Orange


123
John
O,A,
Orange, Apple


456
Jane
O,
Orange


789
Jack
O,A,
Apple, Orange




"Unfortunately, this is not always as simple as using STRING_AGG() to make a CSV of the group codes because it's order of items in indeterminate" you can use WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY so the whole FOR XML mess is unnecessary

Thanks @Charlieface that is true, I had avoided that in the past as it wasn't supported in Azure SQL DB, but yes that makes things a lot simpler.
